# Make sortable elements draggable which can be dropped on a droppable and can be again connected to the list when dragged back

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to use `jQuery-ui` `draggable`, `droppable` and `sortable` together.

My functionality is as below:

- I have a sortable list
- I have created a `div` that is `droppable`
- The sortable items are draggable and could be dropped on the `droppable` in which they could be moved freely inside the `div`
- The draggable items should be connected back to the sortable list when dragged onto the sortable list

I've included some images that may help make this more clear:

[image: A sortable list to the left and an empty div which constrains the movement of a draggable element on the right]

A sortable list to the left and an empty div which constrains the movement of a draggable element on the right.

[image: Element C is moved from sortable list to the div. It can be placed anywhere within this div, but not outside of it. It can also be connected back to the sortable.]

Element C is moved from sortable list to the div. It can be placed anywhere within this div, but not outside of it. It can also be connected back to the sortable.

[image: Element C is connected back to the sortable.]

Element C is connected back to the sortable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Below is my code:**

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable, #trash'
}).disableSelection();

$("#drop_zone").droppable({
    accept: ".connectedSortable li",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        ui.draggable.sortable("destroy");
        ui.draggable.draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#sortable1",
            containment: "#drop_zone"
        });
    }
});



<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable ui-helper-reset">
    <li class="ui-state-default">A</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">B</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">C</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">D</li>
</ul>

<ul id="drop_zone" class="ui-helper-reset"></ul>
```

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/yfc9h4gq/

Comment: Have you tried coding the things yourself? It yes, then you should provide your code and create a DEMO, and if your answer is no, then nobody is going to code on your behalf

Comment: You can do it like http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/6twmwtn1/1/

Comment: Thank you for your responses; I created a modified version of @AliSoltani's answer which is similar to how I was trying it yesterday. Still no luck: http://jsfiddle.net/yfc9h4gq/

Comment: In AliSoltani's answer that you have accepted has a fault. Once you drop the draggable onto the droppable, then you would be able to drag that droppable anywhere further down the droppable which should not be allowed. While in my answer I have  taken care of that issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. You are correct.

Comment: I disagree with @Rahul because your issue is connecting sortable and draggable not contamination. He just copied my solution and added contamination to it. Sometimes some people try it for getting reputations without thinking about issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/djrry3x8/)

I have added a new `<div id="main_container">` that contains the sortable list and the droppable. So now after dropping the element inside the droppable, the droppable would be contained inside the `#main_container`

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main_container">
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable ui-helper-reset">
    <li class="ui-state-default">A</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">B</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">C</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">D</li>
</ul>

<ul id="drop_zone" class="ui-helper-reset"></ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.attr("style", "");
    }
});

$("#drop_zone").droppable({
    accept: ".connectedSortable li",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        ui.draggable.remove();
        var item = ui.draggable.clone();
        item.appendTo($(this));
        item.draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#sortable1",
            containment: "#main_container"
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable ui-helper-reset">
    <li class="ui-state-default">A</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">B</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">C</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">D</li>
</ul>

<ul id="drop_zone" class="ui-helper-reset"></ul>
```

**JS**

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
 stop: function(event, ui){ 
       ui.item.attr("style","");
    }
});

$("#drop_zone").droppable({
    accept: ".connectedSortable li",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function (ev, ui) {        
    var item = ui.draggable.clone();
    ui.draggable.remove();
    item.appendTo($(this));
        item.draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#sortable1",          
        });
    }
});
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/fbq219cx/1/)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!